# Translating Histogram

Tags: histograms, charts, coordinate-transformation

```
SeedRandom[1];
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
Histogram[%, Automatic, "Probability"]
```

The above code produces a histogram like

[image]

I want to translate the figure by say $\{1,1\}$ as follows:

[image]

Can someone help me do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative approach is to use `ChartElementFunction`:

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability", ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
 ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction["GlassRectangle"][1 + #, ##2] &),
 AxesOrigin -> {-3, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
hist = Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability"]

Show[MapAt[Translate[#, {1, 1}] &, hist, {1}], 
 AxesOrigin -> {-3, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 4}, {1, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, post-process `Rectangle`s:

```
Show[hist /. RectangleBox[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}, z___] :> 
             RectangleBox[1 + {x0, y0}, 1 + {x1, y1}, z],
 AxesOrigin -> {-3, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 4}, {1, 1.5}}]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what i needed

Comment: @user13892, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 1):

To shift left-to-right, merely add $1$ to each sampled point:

```
SeedRandom[1];
1 + #& /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
Histogram[%, Automatic, "Probability"]
```

If one lists the vertical axis as "probability," then surely one doesn't want to add $1$ to each abscissa value as that would violate the definition of a probability measure.

Comment: This doesn't add $1$ to vertical axis.

Comment: That's the very point of the answer: adding 1 to the vertical axis makes no sense in the context of a histogram.

Answer (score 1):

You could just re-write the `Ticks`:

```
Histogram[mydata, Automatic, "Probability", 
 Ticks -> {{#, # + 1, {0.015, 0}} & /@  Range[-3, 3], 
           {#, # + 1, {0.015, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 0.35, 0.05]}]
```

[image]

Minor ticks are left as an exercise for the reader.